# How can I load a text file as array that can be loaded element by element?

Tags: python

I have a text file with the following information:

```
SHRO
BJRD
ZNJK
GRMI
```

I want to save them in a way that I can load them line by line. I mean, suppose its name is "name", and I want the 4th column like below:

```
name[3] = "GRMI"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: read the file line by line and split on whitespace.  Show what code you have so far

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    name = f.read().split()
```

EDIT
According to that answer you've posted, I understand that you simply need to print the name in a line and so, the modified code will be this:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    print f.read().split('\n')[12][:4]     # Assuming that all of the those consist of 4 characters.
                                           # That number 12 was just an example.
```

Otherwise,

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    names = f.read().split('\n')
    print names[12].split()[0]            # Again, that number is an example.
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
with open('stationlist', 'r') as f:
    station_names = [line.split()[0] for line in f]
```

If all of the station names are four characters, the list comprehension could be replaced by

```
[line[:4] for line in f]
```